# Change icon class in Jquery with multiple forms

Tags: php, jquery

I have a 10 forms in my page.

I get the current form like that:

```
        var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
```

What I need is to update icon inside my form from warning to success when I make an AJAX call.

But when I do it, all the 10 icons ( 1 x form ) change.

How can I select just 1?

Here is my code:

```
$('.save_category').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
        var tournamentId =   form.data('tournament');
        var categoryId =   form.data('category');
        var settingId =  form.data('setting');

        // I omitted AJAX Call for more readability

        $('.status-icon').removeClass();
        $('.status-icon').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success status-icon');
}
```

How can I do to reach this particular icon ???

My HTML:

```
@foreach($tournament->categoryTournaments as $key => $categoryTournament)
          <div class="panel ">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-11">
                      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-styled"
                         href="#accordion-styled-group{!! $key !!}">

                          <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h6 class="panel-title">
                                  {{trans($categoryTournament->category->name)}}
                              </h6>
                          </div>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-1">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                          @if (is_null($setting))
                              <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-exclamation-sign text-orange-600 status-icon"></i>
                          @else
                              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success status-icon"></i>
                          @endif
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
              <div id="accordion-styled-group{!! $key !!}"
                   class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      {{--FORM--}}
                      @include('categories.categorySettings')
                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>
          @endforeach
```

Comment: Can you show the complete HTML inside one (1) `<div class="panel ">` ? I cant find the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(this)
    .closest('form')
    .find('.status-icon')
    .removeClass()
    .addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success status-icon');
```

Comment: it is not working :( Not doing anything, but not throwing error neither

Comment: If your `<form>` and the `.status-icon` is in a different DIV , try  `.closest('.panel')`

Comment: I know why, form is inside:                       @include('categories.categorySettings'), so icon is outside the form, I have it in an accordion

Comment: If you can show me the complete `.panel` code, that would be better.

Comment: When I insert it in .ajax call, it doesn't work anymore... I had it out to debug faster

Comment: Save first into a variable `var panel = $(this).closest('.panel');` . Because the moment that the ajax call is done, you are already outside of the function call.

Comment: Hahaha :) You can PM me anytime. If you have a strong team but you are not yet satisfied for them now, just continue learning with them and you will notice that you are growing together. Skilled is different from experienced. XP counts.

Comment: I'm happy with my team, but I have no front end developer for now!

Comment: I have another 'easy' issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305356/update-variable-outside-of-ajax-call