# Unable / disable select field on checkbox field with several forms - Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have several form having the same fields: A checkbox (bootstrap switch) and a select

I want that when I pick the checkbox, the select switch to enable / disable

Thing is when I do it, only the first form is working :(

Here is my HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="http://laravel.dev/tournaments/1/categories/6/settings/9" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>
                <input id="isTeam7" name="isTeam" type="hidden" value="0">
                <input class="switch" data-on-text="Si" data-off-text="No" id="isTeam7" name="isTeam" type="checkbox" value="1">

            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <select class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="teamSize" name="teamSize"><option value="0">2</option><option value="1">3</option><option value="2" selected="selected">4</option><option value="3">5</option><option value="4">6</option><option value="5">7</option><option value="6">8</option><option value="7">9</option><option value="8">10</option><option value="9">11</option><option value="10">12</option><option value="11">13</option><option value="12">14</option><option value="13">15</option></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div align="right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save_category" id="save7"><i></i>Guardar
        </button>
    </div>
</form>  
<form method="POST" action="http://laravel.dev/tournaments/1/categories/6/settings/9" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>
                <input id="isTeam8" name="isTeam" type="hidden" value="0">
                <input class="switch" data-on-text="Si" data-off-text="No" id="isTeam8" name="isTeam" type="checkbox" value="1">

            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <select class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="teamSize" name="teamSize"><option value="0">2</option><option value="1">3</option><option value="2" selected="selected">4</option><option value="3">5</option><option value="4">6</option><option value="5">7</option><option value="6">8</option><option value="7">9</option><option value="8">10</option><option value="9">11</option><option value="10">12</option><option value="11">13</option><option value="12">14</option><option value="13">15</option></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div align="right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save_category" id="save8"><i></i>Guardar
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my Jquery

```
    $('input[name="isTeam"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        $('.teamSize').prop('disabled', !isChecked);
    });
```

How can I do so that it work for all the forms in my page???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="isTeam"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $(this).closest('form').find('[name="teamSize"]').prop('disabled', !isChecked);
  });

  $("input[type=\"checkbox\"], input[type=\"radio\"]").not("[data-switch-no-init]").bootstrapSwitch();

});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="http://laravel.dev/tournaments/1/categories/6/settings/9" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label>
        <input id="isTeam7" name="isTeam" type="hidden" value="0">
        <input class="switch" data-on-text="Si" data-off-text="No" id="isTeam7" name="isTeam" type="checkbox" value="1">

      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <select class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="teamSize" name="teamSize">
        <option value="0">2</option>
        <option value="1">3</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">4</option>
        <option value="3">5</option>
        <option value="4">6</option>
        <option value="5">7</option>
        <option value="6">8</option>
        <option value="7">9</option>
        <option value="8">10</option>
        <option value="9">11</option>
        <option value="10">12</option>
        <option value="11">13</option>
        <option value="12">14</option>
        <option value="13">15</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div align="right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save_category" id="save7"><i></i>Guardar
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<form method="POST" action="http://laravel.dev/tournaments/1/categories/6/settings/9" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label>
        <input id="isTeam8" name="isTeam" type="hidden" value="0">
        <input class="switch" data-on-text="Si" data-off-text="No" id="isTeam8" name="isTeam" type="checkbox" value="1">

      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <select class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="teamSize" name="teamSize">
        <option value="0">2</option>
        <option value="1">3</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">4</option>
        <option value="3">5</option>
        <option value="4">6</option>
        <option value="5">7</option>
        <option value="6">8</option>
        <option value="7">9</option>
        <option value="8">10</option>
        <option value="9">11</option>
        <option value="10">12</option>
        <option value="11">13</option>
        <option value="12">14</option>
        <option value="13">15</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div align="right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save_category" id="save8"><i></i>Guardar
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input element with id="teamSize" doesn't have a class called teamSize, thus your jQuery (which is looking for a class, not an id) has nothing to target.

Comment: I had the class but it didn't fix. It seam to update the first Select of all forms only.

Comment: The only other thing I changed in my version was 

 $('input[name="isTeam"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {

became 

 $('input[name="isTeam"]').change(function (event, state) {

I'm not too familiar with bootstrap to know what those other pieces did

Comment: I had to deal with it, with your way, checkbox event will not trigger : http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/events.html